# viewController.view does not showing but it appears when ViewDebugMode

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm creating Slide Menu using `PanGesture` and `addChild`.

Although `ParentViewController` was able to slide to the left, `MenuViewController` placed just to the right of it is not displayed.

However, when you check with `ViewDebug`, it certainly exists and is placed in the expected location.

But why isn't it displayed on the actual screen?

when view was panned
[image]

when View Debug and this button tapped
[image]
[image]

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGesturePanned)))

        let menuViewController = MenuViewController()
        menuViewController.view.frame = CGRect(
            x: view.frame.maxX,
            y: 0,
            width: view.bounds.width,
            height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        view.addSubview(menuViewController.view)
        addChild(menuViewController)
        menuViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    @objc private func panGesturePanned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureView = gesture.view else { return }

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began:
            print()
        case .changed:
            tabBarController?.view.frame.origin.x = min(max(gesture.translation(in: gestureView).x, -240), 0)

        case .cancelled:
            print()

        case .ended:
            print()

        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: share your pan gesture selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving `tabBarController`, but as I understand you want to move `menuViewController`. Try this:

```
@objc private func panGesturePanned(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let gestureView = gesture.view else { return }

        switch gesture.state {
        case .began: break
        case .changed:
            tabBarController?.view.frame.origin.x = max(-menuViewController.view.bounds.width, gesture.translation(in: gestureView).x)
            menuViewController.view.frame.origin.x = max(0, menuViewController.view.bounds.width - gesture.translation(in: gestureView).x)
        case .cancelled: break
        case .ended: break
        default: break
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Sorry for lack of explanation.

I want MenuViewController to be just to the right of ParentViewController.

With this, the position is covered with ParentViewController, and ParentViewController becomes invisible.
@Erumaru

Comment: @son Yeah, check answer

Comment: @son do you need more help?

Comment: Thank you.
Thank you
It was displayed normally.
I wrote `tabBarcontroller.view` to move both `tabBar` and `navigationBar`. Is this impossible? @Erumaru

Comment: @son Yes, you can move both with the same calculation. I will update answer.